# Синхронизация нумерации мониторов в настройках Windows10 и нумерации мониторов получаемык в коде с помощью WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, monitor

Есть ли возможность какой-то синхронизации, при получения списка мониторов с помощью WinAPI, нумерации в списке и нумерации в настройках системы?

Comment: не совсем понимаю вопрос, но может это ищете? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig

Comment: Приведите пример кода, в котором получается какой-то другой порядок. По идее основной монитор всегда идет первым, затем остальные

Comment: @goldstar_lab, Большое Вам спасибо за отклик, моя проблема решилась методом https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors.Он возвращает мне мониторы в нужном порядке.

Comment: @user7860670 Посмотри комментарий выше. благодарность относится и к тебе. Отвечу на свой собственный вопрос сам